# C# Download Manager (Thread, ThreadPool, BeginInvoke, BackgroundWorker)

Tags: winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker, threadpool, begininvoke

So here it is. I want to make some test download manager (winforms), and want to use 4 different ways (managers):
1. BackGroundWorker manager
2. Thread manager
3. ThreadPool manager
4. Delegate.BeginInvoke manager
 Download from ftp. Of course make it async for multidownloading, and when i want to add new download, previous download might still work. So, my problem is architecture. I imagine this smth like:
1) create interface IDownloadManager. Here - enum Status(Idle, download, downloaded, canceled, errorDownloaded), some events (DownloadStarted, DownloadComleted, DownloadCancelled, DownloadStopped), method for Percent, method for Start.
2) ManagerFactory class, that creates selected Manager.
3) IManagerFactory interface, that handle with creating Manager
4) ManagerHost class, where stores all information of current managers.

Can anyone tell me, where is my architecture mistakes? give me some advises, suggestions etc..Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 0):

It seems good. Hope the architecture you designed will work well.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that support for cancellation or progress for all those '4 different ways' will end up with the implementation of the BackgroundWorker. The backgroundworker combines the uses of the threadpool and synchronizationcontext for UI purposes.